# MCP3008 reading wrong values

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi

I'm currently using an MCP3008 ADC with Raspberry Pi and interfacing them with the wiringPi library.

To test the MCP3008 was reading the values properly I set up a voltage divider with a 100kΩ resistor and 100kΩ variable resistor to test a range of voltages.

The values however were around 130 off - which is quite high considering this is a 10-bit ADC.

I repeated the test with a 10kΩ resistor and a 10kΩ variable resistor and the values were accurate. I repeated the test again with 1kΩ resistors and they were accurate again.

So for the same values of voltages for 100kΩ and 10kΩ the MCP3008 gave different values.

The current was obviously lower in the 100kΩ resistors but the MCP3008 was drawing negligable current anyway so I don't think this is a factor.

Just wondering if anyone had any idea why this might be?

Sorry if this isn't worded the best, this is my first time asking on here.

Comment: A small note: the comment "The current was obviously higher in the 100kΩ resistors" makes no sense. For the same voltage, a higher resistance results in a lower current (Ohms Law). Further, these resistors *completely determine* the amount of current available to drive the *input* of the MCP3008. They are not arbitrary choices. They do have practically nothing to do with the amount of power the MCP3008 consumes to operate, so saying the MCP3008 was drawing negligible current is independent of them.

Comment: When you were measuring the voltage, was the voltage steady or were you turning the variable resistor continuously? It sound like it was steady for seconds, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: @gbulmer , yeah my apologies, I have changed this in the original question. The voltage was steady - so when the voltage read 2V, for example, in each test, the values were quite a bit different, when they should have been the same.

Comment: What is the reference?

Comment: 100K is pretty darn high to put on the input of a cheap ADC.

Comment: The reference is 4.85V coming from the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - yeah the 100k is a little high, but it was the first one I had on hand so I just tested with that first.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be surprised to see it forming a voltage divider with the ADC's input resistance.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - I think your comment could be raised to the status of an answer.

Comment: @gbulmer I would, but the data sheet isn't really giving good info on the input resistance.  There's a "switch resistance" on the input to the hold cap, and a funny graph of clock frequency vs input resistance that I can't make head or tail of.  It's probably the input resistance, but I suppose it can be that the high source resistance affected the settle time, too.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - Interesting comment. I thought it was just me missing the 'obvious' piece of information, so I resisted commenting on how poor the datasheet seemed. However, with a second pair of eyes suffering the same problem, I don't feel so bad. I still think you are likely correct, but I also agree that it is hard to be specific.

Comment: What sample rate are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the data sheet isn't ideal for this particular calculation, ADC's have an input resistance, and it is very likely that the high source impedance because of the 100K resistors is forming the high side of a voltage divider, causing some attenuation of your input signal.

It is also possible that the high source impedance is causing a slowdown of the charging of the sample and hold capacitor, and the sample is completed before the settling time is reached.

My bet is the former.

Comment: If the OP told us the sample rate, we *might* be able to improve the odds on the bet. However, +1 for covering the bases.

Comment: I put a capacitor in parallel with the bottom resistor (R2) and this seemed to fix the problem. This capacitor reduces the time constant so the SAR can reach the desired value quicker. 

Thanks for your help.